# Merge text files by column: two column common and append third column form all files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Trying to merge files of the same format of an entire folder to a merged file.

```
head File1.txt
11  116701285   204
11  116701286   209
11  116701287   209
11  116701288   208
11  116701289   209
11  116701290   208
11  116701291   208
11  116701292   210
11  116701293   209
11  116701294   213

head File2.txt
11  116701285   188
11  116701286   192
11  116701287   191
11  116701288   191
11  116701289   191
11  116701291   191
11  116701292   194
11  116701293   194
11  116701294   199
```

.........

```
head FileN.txt
11  116701285   190
11  116701286   192
11  116701287   191
11  116701288   189
11  116701289   191
11  116701290   192
11  116701291   193
11  116701292   197
11  116701293   196
11  116701294   199
```

The desired output (the number of columns after first two columns will correspond to the number of files. First two column is same in all files. There is no header in the file)

```
11  116701285   188 204 190
11  116701286   192 209 192
11  116701287   191 209 191
11  116701288   191 208 189
11  116701289   191 209 191
11  116701290   191 0   192
11  116701291   191 208 193
11  116701292   194 210 197
11  116701293   194 209 196
11  116701294   199 213 199
```

If element the entry is not present fill in 0. Used join but could only do two files.

Comment: So use join in a loop to append the next file to the result of the previous iteration...

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. From the tags you've added, I'd expect to see code in bash and awk, as well as the problematic output (or errors) that your code currently produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '{
   k=$1 OFS $2
}
FNR == NR {
   v[++n] = k
}
{
   a[ARGIND,k] = $3
}
END {
   for(j=1; j<=n; j++) {
      printf "%s", v[j]
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++)
         printf "%s", OFS ((i,v[j]) in a ? a[i,v[j]] : 0)
      print ""
   }
}' File*.txt | column -t
```

```
11  116701285  204  188  190
11  116701286  209  192  192
11  116701287  209  191  191
11  116701288  208  191  189
11  116701289  209  191  191
11  116701290  208  0    192
11  116701291  208  191  193
11  116701292  210  194  197
11  116701293  209  194  196
11  116701294  213  199  199
```

If you want one liner then use:

```
awk '{k=$1 OFS $2} FNR==NR{v[++n]=k} {a[ARGIND,k] = $3} END{for(j=1; j<=n; j++) {printf "%s", v[j]; for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) printf "%s", OFS ((i,v[j]) in a ? a[i,v[j]] : 0); print ""}}' File*.txt
```

`column -t` is used for tabular output.

Comment: Perfect ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next} {a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2] OFS $3:$3} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' File*.txt
```

Comment: Seems to be working... The first column is not there in the output

Comment: change `$3` to `$3+0`.  Also replace `a[$1,$2]?` ternary with simple assignment `a[$1,$2] OFS $3+0`

Comment: @shams: You have shown `11 116701290 191 0 192` in expected output, is that not correct?

Comment: And the problem is first two columns are pasted together `11116701290` instead of `11     116701290`

Comment: @karakfa, still get the same answer. The merging of $1 and $2 is there along with empty space for the missing values instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
#!/bin/bash
## Assuming all your file are named as *FileN.txt* and so on
endresult="$( awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}'  File1.txt )"
for file in F*.txt
do 

    endresult=$( paste <( echo "$endresult" ) <( awk '{ if(length($3) != 0) { print $3 }else{print 0}}'  $file ) ) 

done

#Replacing empty values for zeroes
endresult=$( echo "$endresult" | awk -v max_rows=$( echo "$endresult" | awk '{print NF}' | sort -r | head -1 ) 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }{ for(i=1;i < (max_rows + 1);i++) {  if(length($i) == 0 ){  $i = 0 } } ; print $0}' )
```

#### Edit : Im grabbing the first two columns from the 1st file as you stated these two were equal in all files.

Regards!